# Animation from the 1990s-2010s which happens on a planet with pandas who get powers from special objects to save a world

Tags: story-identification, animation

When I was young I used to watch an animation on TV somewhere between the 1990s and 2010s. If I remember correctly there was a peaceful kingdom on one planet but was attacked by an evil being so the royal family sent their daughter to a different planet to look for special objects and people who can use the power from the objects and she landed on a planet with pandas.
If I remember correctly there was an ordinary panda, a news panda who dressed up like a super hero with a cape, one was a chef, there was a brother and sister who fused into some kind of chimera.

Sorry if the information is not enough but that is all I can remember from the past. Thanks if you can help identify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Pandalian*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandalian)

> It follows the story of a fairy named Mi who is sent to Planet Pandasia to warn the residents about a great evil that threatens to destroy Pandasia. She chooses a heroic panda named Toby to defeat King Audie and his minions, Gold and Silver, who want to collect the seven Beans of Power and rid Pandasia of its colourful, beautiful environment and replace it with a dark wasteland.

### Opening Credits

Found with a search for `cartoon planet pandas` although I had to scroll through a lot of irrelevant results, and was about to plug in more clarifying terms.

Comment: FuzzyBoots   thanks for the help. that is exactly the animation I was looking for. Thank you very much.